Python: Adding a command button named "Plot scores" to the user interface that displays a line plot of the student's test scores
I'm creating a program that takes a student's information and test scores and generates a GUI that calculates their mean, median, mode, and standard deviation. It also requires there to be a Plot scores button that displays a line plot of the student's test scores. However, I keep running into the following error:

TypeError: StudentView.init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'student'

Could someone please help me in figuring out what I'm doing wrong with this code. I have tried multiple times to get it right.
Here are the codes I'm working with:
student.py

class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_id, name):
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.name = name
        self.test_scores = []

    def add_test_score(self, score):
        self.test_scores.append(score)

    def average_test_score(self):
        if len(self.test_scores) == 0:
            return 0
        return sum(self.test_scores)/len(self.test_scores)

    def get_test_scores(self):
        return self.test_scores

studentview.py

from breezypythongui import EasyFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from student import Student

class StudentView(EasyFrame):

    def __init__(self, model, student):
        EasyFrame.__init__(self)
        self.setSize(500, 200)
        self.model = model
        self.student = student
        student = Student(model.student_id, model.name, model.test_scores)
        student_view = StudentView(model, student)
        self.addLabel("Mean", row = 0, column = 0)
        self.addLabel("Median", row = 1, column = 0)
        self.addLabel("Mode", row = 2, column = 0)
        self.addLabel("Standard deviation", row = 3, column = 0)

        self.meanFld = self.addFloatField(value = 0.0, row = 0, column = 1, precision = 2)
        self.medianFld = self.addFloatField(value = 0.0, row = 1, column = 1, precision = 2)
        self.modeFld = self.addFloatField(value = 0.0, row = 2, column = 1, precision = 2)
        self.stdFld = self.addFloatField(value = 0.0, row = 3, column = 1, precision = 4)
        self.addLabel("Data", row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "NEW")
        self.scoreArea = self.addTextArea(text = "", row = 1, column = 2, width = 12, rowspan = 3)

        bp = self.addPanel(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 3, background = "black")
        bp.addButton(text = "Edit Score", row = 0, column = 0, command = self.editScore)
        bp.addButton(text = "Add score", row = 0, column = 1, command = self.addScore)
        bp.addButton(text = "Randomize scores", row = 0, column = 3, command = self.randomizeScores)
        bp.addButton(text="Plot Scores", row=0, column=4, command=self.plotScores)

        self.refreshData()

    def plotScores(self):
        scores = self.student.get_test_scores()
        positions = list(range(1, len(scores) + 1))
        plt.plot(positions, scores, marker='o')
        plt.xlabel('Positions')
        plt.ylabel('Scores')
        plt.title('Student Test Scores')
        plt.show()

studentapp.py

"""
File: studentapp.py
The application for editing and analyzing student scores.
"""

from student import Student
from studentview import StudentView

def main():
    """Creates the model and view and starts the app."""
    model = Student("Ken", 10)
    StudentView(model)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

stats.py

"""
File: stats.py

Defines functions to compute the mean, median, std, and mode
of a list of numbers.
"""

import math
import random

def mean(lyst):
    """Returns the mean of a list of numbers."""
    return sum(lyst) / len(lyst)

def frequencies(lyst):
    """Returns a dictionary keyed by the unique
    numbers and their frequencies in lyst."""
    # Obtain the set of unique numbers and their
    # frequencies, saving these associations in
    # a dictionary
    theDictionary = {}
    for number in lyst:
        freq = theDictionary.get(number, 0)
        theDictionary[number] = freq + 1
    return theDictionary

def mode(lyst):
    """Returns the mode of a list of numbers."""
    theDictionary = frequencies(lyst)
    theMaximum = max(theDictionary.values())
    for key in theDictionary:
        if theDictionary[key] == theMaximum:
            result = key
            break
    return result

def modes(lyst):
    """Returns the modes of a list of numbers."""
    # Obtain the set of unique numbers and their
    # frequencies, saving these associations in
    # a dictionary
    theDictionary = frequencies(lyst)
    theMaximum = max(theDictionary.values())
    result = []
    for key in theDictionary:
        if theDictionary[key] == theMaximum:
            result.append(key)
    return result

def median(lyst):
    """Precondition: lyst is non-empty.
    Returns the median of numbers in lyst."""
    if len(lyst) == 0: 
        raise RuntimeError("List must be non-empty. ")
    copy = list(lyst)
    copy.sort()
    midpoint = len(lyst) // 2
    if len(lyst) % 2 == 1:
        return copy[midpoint]
    else:
        return mean([copy[midpoint - 1], copy[midpoint]])

def std(lyst):
    """Precondition: lyst is non-empty.
    Returns the standard deviation of the numbers in lyst."""
    if len(lyst) == 0: 
        raise RuntimeError("List must be non-empty. ")
    average = mean(lyst)
    differences = map(lambda x: x - average, lyst)
    squares = list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, differences))
    return math.sqrt(mean(squares))

def getRandomList(size, lower, upper, unique = False):
    """Returns a list of randomly generate numbers
    within the given bounds."""
    theList = []
    for count in range(size):
        number = random.randint(lower, upper)
        if unique:
            while number in theList:
                number = random.randint(lower, upper)
        theList.append(number)
    return theList

def main():
    """Tests the functions."""
    lyst = [3, 1, 7, 1, 4, 10]
    print("List:", lyst)
    print("Mode:", mode(lyst))
    print("Median:", median(lyst))
    print("Mean:", mean(lyst))
    print("Standard deviation:", std(lyst))    
    print("Frequencies:", frequencies(lyst))
    lyst.sort()
    print(lyst)
    lyst = [3, 1, 7, 1, 4]
    print("List:", lyst)
    print("Mode:", mode(lyst))
    print("Median:", median(lyst))
    print("Mean:", mean(lyst))
    print("Standard deviation:", std(lyst))    
    print("Frequencies:", frequencies(lyst))
    lyst.sort()
    print(lyst)
    lyst = getRandomList(10, 1, 10)
    print(lyst)
    lyst = getRandomList(10, 1, 10, unique = True)
    print(lyst)
    

# The entry point for program execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
     


Why does the constructor of StudentView create another separate StudentView inside of it?

At the init function of your StudentView you ask for 2 parameters, model and student. Yet when you create a StudentView object in the main function of studentapp.py you only provide one parameter model. That's where the error comes from.
